# How to convert 12v-15v input to 9v?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am on my first projects in electronics to refresh my old rusted knowledge and to updated also.

I have a not so stable input about 12v to 15v maximum and i want to convert it to 9v and use it to recharge 9v batteries (9v Ni-Cd 160 mAh and 9v Ni-Mh 300 mAh)

I dont want much heat or too many components on it cause of little space for the circuit so i would like to try as my first projects to make it with zener diode and a resistance but since i am like noob in this area and search around didnt came up so handy and understandable
i would like to know first of all if it can be done in this way and if is possible to stabilize an input of 12v - 15v to 9v for my batteries and what zener type do i look for and what combination of resistance with zener ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will not achieve this with a zener and a resistor. You better also read up on chargers for NiCd and NiMh batteries. Neither one of these is safely charged simply by attaching them to a fixed voltage source.

Comment: A zener shunt regulator isn't a very good fit for this. Your simplest solution is a 7809, but that will make heat as it's a linear regulator. For less heat you want a buck converter, but with those complexity increases. Don't just put 9v across the batteries to charge them.

Comment: @Michael yes i will look at them but first i need to know how to convert the input at least at 9v

Comment: @Colin__s is there any link or somewhere to learn about buck converters ?

Comment: Google is quite popular.

Comment: @Colin__s I was asking if you have something in mind for the specific convertions otherwise thanks for the response

Comment: Actually Nocs, what they're getting at is that you wouldn't have a circuit to produce a 9 V supply then put that into a charging circuit, you'd do both in one circuit. It's smaller and uses fewer parts, like you wanted. Follow their recommendations and read up on battery chargers. No-one's going to type a long solution in for you that can be readily found on the internet. Good luck.

Comment: Read about chargers first. Those two battery technologies have different charging requirements. And for charging a 9V battery it is not as simple as starting with a 9V supply. Chargers will have other requirements than a simple 9V input.

Comment: @Michael i will have a look then at battery requirements, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating this.

And most comments/answer focus on getting 9V while **you do not need 9 V !!**

The reason for this is that you ask "How to convert 12v-15v input to 9v?" while your real question is: "How can I charge a 9 V NiCd/NiMh battery from 12 - 15 V ?"

So I think you just want to charge a 9 V NiCd or NiMh battery from a 12 V - 15 V source.

You think you would need 9 V to charge the batteries but the truth is **you don't need 9 V !!**

Luckily NiCd and NiMh batteries are **extremely easy** to charge. As long as you charge them with a **small current**.

This is the circuit you need:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGVLZl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The "challenge" is to properly calculate the value of Rcharge.
It is common to charge these NiCd or NiMh batteries with C/10 so for the
160 mAh battery that means 16 mA and for the 300 mAh it means 30 mA.

Lets stick with that 16 mA, you can charge the 300 mAh battery with 16 mA as well, it will just take longer.

Your power source provides maximum 15 V DC so that leavs 15 V - 9 V = 6 V across R charge.

Enter Ohm's law: 6 V / 16 mA = 375 ohms. These are hard to find but  390 ohms is close enough and easy to buy.

To charge the 300 mAh battery you can also place 2 of these 390 ohm resistors in parallel, then you'd get close to 30 mA, which is perfect for that battery.

Comment: Thanks fake moustache, i asked like this cause nowhere i have found an answer like this till now, they all talk about heat and cells and blah blah blah and not the basic how to start and what it needs and then go the details of the protection of overcharge and undercharge. Thanks really appreciated

Comment: Reading your question properly, in the sense of really understanding what **you** need is difficult. Many people trigger on the zenerdiode and the 9 V instead of taking a step back and really seeing what your problem is. The circuit you need is one resistor, nice and simple huh ? :-) If you like my answer, be a good citizen and accept it (there's a button for that).

Comment: sure will be a best answer no hard feelings for the others cause is indeed a simple and easy one as a newbie like me would love to hear and had to learn

Comment: The others were only trying to help of course. Also, almost no-one uses 9V NiCd or NiMh batteries anymore, many people forget how easy these are regarding charging (compared to Lithium based batteries, then a chip is needed).

Comment: i have left the fields of electronics for about 10 years and now that i making again some steps i found many new stuff around and too much to get to know again

Answer (score 0):

using linear regulators with fixed 9v o/p or a configurable o/p (mostly involves a passive components for the feedback part of the circuit) for this purpose.

Example:  IC-7809 linear regulator

Along with regulator/DC step down converter, you need to have a battery charging circuit to control the charging process.

Also,if your design involves charging a 9V battery, then you need to have a regulator o/p of around 15V being fed to the charging circuit.

Comment: Thank you duster too for your answer, it was in my options to use a voltage or linear regulator if i needed to lower the volts but if it was i was trying to find a non too much heating way and loss of amps while redusing volts